# Calculating Diffie Hellman Challenge - Python vs NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, biginteger, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to calculate the Diffie-Hellman Challenge in Python based on the algorithm from a NodeJS client app.  The code for the NodeJS client app is as follows:

```
var a = crypto.randomBytes(25).toString('hex');
var p = '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'
var g = 2
const A = bigInteger(g).modPow(bigInteger(a, 16), bigInteger(p, 16));
```

The NodeJS app successfully makes the calculation for `A` and prints the value out as a string in the browser console.

On the other hand, when I use the algorithm in my local Python server, the calculation for `A` doesn't finish in a timely manner (in fact, the browser has been spinning this whole time while writing this question).  Here is the Python code:

```
 a = secrets.token_hex(25)
 A = (g**int(a, 16)) % int(p, 16)
```

Can someone tell me why NodeJS can finish the calculation but Python cannot?  Should I be using some crypto library to handle Diffie-Hellman verification?  How can I get past this issue?

Comment: Why does `p` end with four v's? v is not a valid hex character.

Comment: My bad. I randomly typed a hexadecimal prime and didn't realize that I accidentally inserted four v's at the end.  I hope my oversight didn't totally distract you from the point of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in function [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) can be passed a third `mod` argument to get the modulus of number raised to the power of another, like the `modPow` function you are calling

```
A = pow(g, int(a, 16), int(p, 16))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm!  Any idea why `A = (g**int(a, 16)) % int(p, 16)` gets "stuck" but the pow function works?

Comment: @Vee: Think about the size of g\*\*a. You're asking to generate a number 2\*\*200 bits in size, on a computer that has about 2\*\*40 or so bits of storage.

Comment: Right.  I understand the hardware liimitations.  But why would the pow function work?